# PhpStorm saying PostgreSQL database does not exist?

Tags: postgresql, phpstorm

I am able to connect to the `protomolecule` database with these exact same credentials through a PHP script. Trying to set it up in PhpStorm fails as you can see in the picture.

If I change the `protomolecule` database to the default `postgres` database it connects just fine in PhpStorm. I can't figure out why the user can only connect to `postgres` and nothing else.

I've tried setting up a new user and new databases to no avail.

[image: PhpStorm Data Sources and Drivers window]

**Edit**: Added the working PHP script settings below, as requested.

```
array(
    'database' => 'protomolecule',
    'driver' => 'Pgsql',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'postgres',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'port' => '5432'
)
```

Comment: Is the user running the PHP script and running PHPStorm the same? If not I guess you have a permission issue.
Could you maybe show the PHP script where the connection works as well?

Comment: The PHP script is a simple PDO connection to PostgreSQL using the same credentials you see in the screenshot above for PhpStorm. I agree it could be permissions, permissions on what though? The user postgres owns the protomolecule database. Thanks.

Comment: check your firewall settings. May be PHPStorm banned!

Comment: I have Windows firewall off  No other firewall to speak of. And the Posters user can connect to Postgres DB fine, just not ones with another name.

Comment: offhand, I would try putting the IP address in instead of localhost. I would also check to see if you need to add or remove any proxy settings in PhpStorm.

Comment: Could you show PHP connection settings?

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky Added them to the bottom of the post. Thanks.

Comment: Do you run your php application on the same host? Do you use virtualmachines, containers like Docker, etc?

Comment: Remove the URL, remove the database, fill the password then press the "Test connection" button. If it works then go to the "Options" tab and you should see there the list of databases accessible to the user you use to connect.

Answer (score 1):

In the image there is an url given. It states that this "overrides settings above". In the url there is no username/password. Can you try adding username (and maybe password too) to the url - or empty the url field.

Answer (score 1):

Check if

1. You can view your postgres database from a dashboard (like phpmyadmin)
2. did you check your permissions on the table?
   normally if in the code it connects with no problems, then it should work in phpstorm.
   But your url seems strange,try changing it with `localhost:5432/protomolecule`